# Regular expression for number and slash

Tags: c#, regex

I do not know regular expressions and going crazy to find one that accepts formats consisting on numbers and slash. For example:

- 5
- 5/10
- 10/15/30
- 10/20/120
- 20/120/250/300

Comment: Your English is OK, but the question is not. What regex/code have you tried?

Comment: `^\d+(?:\/\d+)*$`

Comment: `(\d\/*)+` would work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

`^\d+(\/\d+)*$`

Look at the [examples](http://rubular.com/r/j45HJcSTfV).

This means:

1. My string must begin (`^`) with a one or more digit (`\d+`)
2. Optionally (`(..)*`) followed by a slash **and** one or more digit (`\/\d+`), even many times (`*` means from 0 to many)
3. And then it must end (`$`).

Comment: Why do you think it should work? `^\d+(\/\d+)*` won't work for sure.

Comment: OP doesn't seem well versed in regex, it is definitely worth adding an explanation for them - seems like a failed attempt at FGITW to me

Comment: Thank you @Andrea Salicetti

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
^[0-9]+(\/[0-9]+)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

`(\d+\/?\d?+)` this works fine for me, you can test it here
[**Test Online**](https://regex101.com/r/QntvVR/1)